# How should the MVC structure should look like in android studio using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, model-view-controller

Like I want to know with a well described diagram or steps which can help me to know about the structure of the android studio with MVC structure following, basically how should a project structure should look after it is created with MVC in android studio.

Am new to this I was in spring boot development full stack so is it somehow similar to that or its different?

Open for all types of answers and your valuable explanations

I just got a old project but I cant understand the structure its following and how its using MVC there.